# How can I continue to play my GIF during JavaScript processing (as it freezes)?

Tags: javascript, freeze, animated-gif

My GIF image freezes after 5 seconds while my JavaScript code is doing some work. It unfreezes when procesing is finished.

Is there a solution to animate my GIF while the code is executing?

Here's my JavaScript code:

```
var play = function() {
    var image = document.getElementById('img');
    image.style.display="block";

    window.setTimeout(function(){
        for ( var i =0; i < 2000000000; i++ )
        {
            //Do nothing, in example
        }
    }, 5000);
};

var stop = function() {
    var image = document.getElementById('img');
    image.style.display="none";
};
```

HTML code:

```
<img id="img" src="loader.gif" style="display: none;"/>
<button id="Start" onclick="play()">Play</button>
<button id="Stop" onclick="stop()">Stop</button>
```

Comment: What on earth does *treatment* mean?

Comment: You lock up the browser, it stops...

Comment: I mean what I'll put in 'for' by treatment.

Comment: I'm totally not following this, sorry.

Comment: @epascarello : Yes, but I want to continue to animate my gif when I enter in my 'for ( var i =0; i < 2000000000; i++ )'.

Comment: You lock up the browser...it can not run...Without knowing what is happening in the loop, it is basically impossible to give you pointers on how to fix your problem.

Comment: @epascarello : I know, but browser is unlock when i = 2000000000;

Comment: Because animations can run since the single thread is unlocked...

Comment: @epascarello : This is just for example. Thereafter I will place code that requires a lot of processing. I would like to know if there is a solution to animate my gif during this treatment. Something like running in a thread, but JavaScript does not manage.

Comment: The solution depends on what you are doing! WebWorkers if it is processing something or breaking it up into chunks with minimal writes to the DOM.

Comment: Referred to in *[What to do when a language barrier makes a post unclear?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260994/what-to-do-when-a-language-barrier-makes-a-post-unclear?cb=1#comment45055_260994)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that in this case you should use [webworker elements](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp). They allow you to do some asynchronous operation in the background of the UI elements.

#### One example

```
<p>Value passed by the worker: <output id="result"></output></p>
<script>
    var worker = new Worker('worker.js');

    worker.onmessage = function (event) {
        document.getElementById('result').textContent = event.data;
    };
</script>
```

In a separate file (worker.js):

```
var n = 1;
search: while (true) {
    n += 1;

    for (var i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i += 1)
        if (n % i == 0)
            continue search;

    // Found a prime!
    postMessage(n);
}
```

Every time that you call `postMessage` you send some data from the background (that fires `onmessage` event of the worker element ) to the main thread.

Have a look at [Using jQuery UI progress bar with MVVM, Knockout and web workers](http://www.piotrwalat.net/using-jquery-ui-progress-bar-with-mvvm-knockout-and-web-workers/) for your case:

> In this post I would like to explore:
>
> - How to use the jQuery UI progress bar with [KnockoutJS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KnockoutJS) and [MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) pattern, as a simple example of reusing existing JavaScript UI components.
> - How to use web workers to execute long running task asynchronously and notify view model about the results and progress.

Comment: Well that would work in certain cases...depends on what is happening in the loop.

Comment: @epascarello sure!! be careful with the code in the loop

Comment: @faby : Thanks. but woker is not appropriate in my case. I'm using the design pattern MVVM with knockout framework :/

Comment: @user3756615 have a lokk here http://www.piotrwalat.net/using-jquery-ui-progress-bar-with-mvvm-knockout-and-web-workers/

Comment: I've added the link in the answer @user3756615

Comment: @faby Sorry, I didn't see it :/

Comment: I've added it now.. happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use yield as in this working example with minor mod's to your own code...

```js
var play = function() {
//'-----------------------------------Insert Handler..
      var obj = myfuncGen.next(); //'start it
      if (obj.done == false) {
          setTimeout(play, 150); //'adjust for the amount of time you wish to yield (depends how much screen drawing is required or etc)
      } 
  }
  var myfuncGen = myfuncSurrogate(); //'creates a "Generator" out of next. 
  function* myfuncSurrogate() { //'This the original function repackaged! Note asterisk. 
//'-------------------------------------End Insert
  var image = document.getElementById('img');
    image.style.display="block";

    //window.setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("start");
        for ( var i =0; i < 20000000; i++ )
        {
          if ((i % 1000000) == 0) { //a yield set to go off every 1,000,000 loops (if the yield is called too often it will needlessly slowe down yor loop)
            console.log("yielding ", i / 1000000);
            yield;
          }
        }
        console.log("done");
    //}, 500);
};

play()
```

```html
<img id='img' src='http://bestanimations.com/Earth&Space/Earth/earth-spinning-rotating-animation-52.gif' />
```

..I had to edit out `window.setTimeout()` as it created a detached function which causes an error with Yield. To restore your original intent, I would call `play()` from such a timeout.

If the link becomes broken to the random gif I chose, I am sure you could substitute another :-).